# Passing any arbitrary function as a property value to Typescript React Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my React component, I want to define a property to accept any arbitrary function which returns a value. I do not want to worry about the number of arguments it take.. All that matters to me in the return value of that function.

**Some sample expected usages:**

```js
<MyComponent getData={function1()}/>
<MyComponent getData={function2(1,2)}/>
<MyComponent getData={function3("hello")}/>
```

Currently I have defined my component property interface as below.

```js
interface MyComponentProps {
  getData: (...args: any[]) => any;
}
```

With the above declarations, I get that `getData is not a function` error in console.

But the below variations work.

```js
<MyComponent getData={() => function1()}/>
<MyComponent getData={() => function2(1,2)}/>
<MyComponent getData={() => function3("hello")}/>
```

How should I change my type definition so that I can pass any function as a value to the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function1()` and `function2(1, 2)` *call* functions, so let's say that `function1()` returns a string. In that case, this would be like `getData="some-string"` which is indeed not a function.

In the second example, you have a function that itself calls a function.

You could also write these as `getData={function1.bind()}`, `getData={function2.bind(null, 1, 2)}`, but I think that using the arrow function as in your second example is preferred.

You could also use named functions as in

```
function2Caller() { function2(1, 2); }
...
getData={function2Caller}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface should be:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  getData: () => void;
}
```

this way you can pass any function to `getData`

Comment: I have tried the same as my first try and the results are same.